# Gmail Atom Feed Doesn't Return Anything

Tags: javascript, email, xmlhttprequest, gmail, gmail-api

I would like use the [Gmail atom feed](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom) in order to get the `<fullcount>` value in the XML. I've tried various things and looked all over Google, but none of the answers have really worked yet.
Here's my code so far:

```
<script>

var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
    {// and then there's IE6 and IE5.
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("fullcount") + " Unread Emails");
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

I am currently using Firefox v 35.0.1. Sorry, javascript isn't my strong suit. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are there "UNREAD" emails in you inbox? you will get result only when you have unread emails in the inbox. Also, check this link for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467432/gmail-atom-feed

Comment: Ah, silly me! I you probably need to be authenticated first :P Is it too much to maybe show me an example of a script that authenticates you, and then returns a live feed of unread emails? If not, I appreciate the help anyways.

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js on how to authenticate oauth with java script

Comment: Thanks! I've referenced the link you sent me, and [this is my code](http://pastebin.com/z2undzXZ)... it works until it gets to the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()